# Handling SQL Server connections with VB ASP

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Hello am trying to handle multiple database connections on a single form, i have some code but cannot implement it with any luck. So my questions is what is the best way to implement a try catch and where would i call the method to handle the connections ill give an example of my code.

```
<script runat="server">    
    Protected Sub SqlDataSource12_Selecting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs)
    End Sub

    Protected Sub loadMe(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)    
        Try
            Dim conn As New Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("BODataConnectionString54").ConnectionString)
            conn.Open()
            conn.Close()
            ListView3.DataSourceID = "SqlDataSource12"
        Catch ex As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
            error10.Visible = True
        End Try  
      End Sub

    Protected Sub ListView3_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

    End Sub 
</script>
```

And i implement loadMe to the body.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="topContent" Runat="Server" >
    <body id="Body1" runat="server" onload="loadMe">
```

The ListView3_SelectedIndexChanged to the ListView.

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView3" runat="server" ItemPlaceholderID="itemPlaceHolder1" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource12" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ListView3_SelectedIndexChanged">
```

The SqlDataSource12_Selecting to the SqlDataSource.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource12" runat="server" ConnectionString="
<%$ ConnectionStrings:BODataConnectionString54 %>" 
                   SelectCommand="SELECT..... "
                   onselecting="SqlDataSource12_Selecting"
                   ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:BODataConnectionString54.ProviderName %>">
                        <SelectParameters>
```

And last the message i would like the catch to show when the connection to the database is not there.

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="error10" Text="Store could not be loaded" Visible="False" />
```

Any help would be great thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i figured out i only needed the one try catch "loadMe", and i added "ListView3.Visible = False" inside the catch and added "Visible="True"" to "ListView3".
here is an example

```
<script runat="server">


    Protected Sub loadMe(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)


        Try
            Dim conn As New Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("BODataConnectionString54").ConnectionString)
            conn.Open()
            conn.Close()
            ListView3.DataSourceID = "SqlDataSource12"
        Catch ex As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException           
            ListView3.Visible = False
            error10.Visible = True
        End Try


    End Sub


</script>
..
...
....
   <body id="Body1" runat="server" onload="loadMe">
..
...
....
   <asp:ListView ID="ListView3" runat="server" Visible="True" ItemPlaceholderID="itemPlaceHolder1" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource12" >
```